# Spotify web API gives 500 errors often

Tags: python, django, spotify, python-requests

I am building an app that interfaces with the spotify web API using the python package 'spotipy'.

However, I randomly will get 500 errors like so:

```
http status: 500, code:-1 - the requested resource could not be found: https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/[USERNAME]/playlists
```

Here is what my workflow looks like (minus my api key info)

```
client_id = '' 
client_secret = ''
redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/spotify/'
scope = 'playlist-read-private user-read-private playlist-modify-private'
auth = oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, scope = scope)

def spotify_auth(request):
    auth_url = auth.get_authorize_url()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_url)
```

After the user is authenticated, they are redirected to the following view:

```
def spotify(request):
    token_code = request.GET.get('code')
    token = auth.get_access_token(token_code)
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token['access_token'])
    user = sp.me()
    playlists = sp.user_playlists(user['id'])
```

At which point, I will get a 500 error often (but not always)...

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint for fetching a user's playlists was a bit borked yesterday, but today it seems to work fine. I would try it again.